# Best matching between two arrays using fuzzy string matching

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I need a way to find the best matching between two arrays.

Array `a` contains product names
Array `b` refers to all the same products but the names may differ slightly.

```
a = [
    "F542521376-34-REG",
    "AF7U",
    "AF106U",
    "F521521376-30R"
]

b = [
    "F54252137634R",
    "AF7U",
    "AF106U",
    "F52152137630R"
]
```

Best matching:

```
"F542521376-34-REG" - "F54252137634R"
"AF7U"              - "AF7U"
"AF106U"            - "AF106U"
"F521521376-30R"    - "F52152137630R"
```

or:

```
a[0] - b[0]
a[1] - b[1]
a[2] - b[2]
a[3] - b[3]
```

*(The first and last elements varied between lists.)*

I can use a fuzzy string matching algorithm to get a numerical value for string similarity (0.0-1.0). But that alone wont get me to the best possible matching of the list elements. I've not found an algorithm for this and I don't want to brute force it.

The actual application for this is, I have some middle-man ruby code that translates information between two third party systems and the data quality is all over the place. I need to match the elements to create a look-up table. There is no telling what the formatting and mutations of the product "names" might be.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that I used the gem [fuzzy_match](https://github.com/seamusabshere/fuzzy_match) to solve. 
This proposal assumes that the relationship between a and b is not necessarily one to one.

```
require 'fuzzy_match'

fz=FuzzyMatch.new(a)

map = {}
map[nil] = []   # elements in b with no match in a 
a.each{|r| map[r] = []} # In case more than one element in b match a

b.each do |name|
 map[fz.find(name)] << name
end
```

This gives "map":

```
{"F542521376-34-REG"=>["F54252137634R"],
 "AF7U"=>["AF7U"],
 "AF106U"=>["AF106U"],
 "F521521376-30R"=>["F52152137630R"]}
```

If the match is not good enough there are several parameters to fuzzy_match that can be used to improve the matching result.

Answer (score 0):

```
(a & b).size.to_f / a.size # or b.size, depends on your needs
```

Comment: Please add brief explanation to your answer about how does it work.

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe I was misleading. I need a method to sort (or otherwise link) two arrays based element best matches.